# Plotly: How to set y-axis ticklabels inside the plot / to the right of the axis?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

With a plot such as this:

[image]

How can you set the y-axis tick-labels inside the plot, or to the right of the y-axis?

#### Code

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)-1
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y="GOOG")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature that has been asked about in numerous forms on SO the last few years - often as an addition to a more detailed question. After `Plotly version 4.14` this can easily be done through, for example:

```
ticklabelposition="inside top"
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)-1
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y="GOOG")
fig.update_yaxes(ticklabelposition="inside top", title=None)
fig.show()
```